# Resize background image only if resolution exceeds image size

Tags: css

So I found a [tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) that resizes the background image of your website based on the aspect ratio of the browser. This works, but I only want it to crop and resize the image if the browser is at such a high resolution that it will not fit.

It uses

```
background-size: cover;
```

which does the trick, but I only want it to change the size if its more than the original size. IN OTHER WORDS: I only want it to make the background bigger, not smaller.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

u want fix size of background u can use this.

```
page{
       with:960px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        background:black;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the width of your background image you can use media queries to achieve what you want.

For example, let's say your background-image is 900px wide:

```
body {
    background: url('/img/background.jpg') no-repeat left top;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    body {
        background-size: cover;     
    }
}
```

This will set the background-size: cover property for screen sizes 900px and above, but will keep the original size for smaller screens.

*A reference of which browsers support media queries: http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries*